# CSS for JS button works on Local machine but not server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm working with a series of JS open/close buttons. Tests perfectly on local machine but when uploaded only works on non-IE browsers (surprise there.)

The paths are all correct, triple checked. Plus they work in non-IE browsers.

CSS for the button

```
.bluebutton{
-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px;
-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
background-color:#e0e0e0;
border:0;
color:#333;
cursor:pointer;
font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
margin:0;padding:5px;
text-decoration:none;text-align:center;font-size:15px;font-weight:400; 
border-bottom:2px inset #cccccc;
position:relative;display:block;
width:100%;
}
```

markup

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('.blue').hide().before('<a href="#" id="toggle-blue" class="bluebutton">Primary Text <br> Subtext</a>');
 $('a#toggle-blue').click(function() {
    $('.blue').slideToggle(1000);
    return false;
 });
 });
 </script>

<div class="blue">Text</div>
```

The buttons do work if I manually format each of them. Problem is I'm creating a very large accordion style menu with 4 layers of buttons and manual formatting of these eats up like 200kb. See below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('.blue').hide().before('<a href="#" id="toggle-blue" class="button" style="width:100%;display:block;height:40px;color:#e0e0e0;font-weight:bold;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:18px;text-align:center;padding:5px 0px;margin:0;">Primary text <br> Subtext</a>');
$('a#toggle-blue').click(function() {
    $('.blue').slideToggle(1000);
    return false;
});
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: What does it do in IE?

Comment: It creates just a line of text as if it were <p> with a blue background. The JS still works and I can open and close the button, but it lacks the block shape and text formatting.

Comment: IE might be triggering compatibility view when the page is viewed over HTTP at an actual URL.  Open the dev tools (F12) and check if IE is using the compatibility view or an older mode.

Comment: That does seem to have some impact. Read IE9 at first, but switched modes to IE8 and IE9. Both refreshed the page to work correctly. Think this will resolve the problem?    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE">

Comment: Have you tried creating the element instead of passing it as a string? `.before($('<a>').addClass("button").attr('href', '#").attr('id', 'toggle-blue').text('subtext'))` - IE has a nice habit of not rendering elements if they're added as strings in some cases.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with JS as I am with CSS or HTML. I'll do some research into that suggestion. Thanks Kai.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like my problem was IE rendering things in compatibility mode. Adding:
     `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE">` to my head
did help out. Thanks all for your comments and suggestions.